# Gap/Island problem, consecutive days flagged with reset

Tags: powerbi, gaps-and-islands

Was hoping to get some help from Power BI gurus on this forum. I have a table of data of which I'm trying to obtain the Target Result column in Power BI.

| Date | Account | Flag | Target Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/3/23 | ABC | 1 | 1 |
| 1/3/23 | DEF | 1 | 1 |
| 1/3/23 | GHI | 1 | 1 |
| 1/3/23 | JKL | 1 | 1 |
| 1/4/23 | ABC | 1 | 2 |
| 1/4/23 | DEF | 0 | 0 |
| 1/4/23 | GHI | 0 | 0 |
| 1/4/23 | JKL | 1 | 2 |
| 1/5/23 | ABC | 1 | 3 |
| 1/5/23 | DEF | 1 | 1 |
| 1/4/23 | GHI | 0 | 0 |
| 1/4/23 | JKL | 1 | 3 |

From some googling around, I believe this is a standard gaps and islands type problem, but, given I'm not great with DAX, I can't seem to adjust what I've found to work for my use case.

As you can see from the table, the idea is that the Target Result column will count consecutive days where Flag = 1 for a specific account, but reset to 0 if the Flag column for an account resets to 0. Account ABC, for example shows 3 on 1/5/23 because Flag = 1 for each day, but DEF shows 1 on the same date because Flag = 0 for that account on 1/4/23 and Target Result = 1 on 1/5/23 when Flag = 1.

I'm not exactly sure where to start so any help much appreciated.
Thanks very much.

Comment: Apologies.  I was attempting to provide a much smaller version of the actual dataset. Bottom line is that i'm trying to count consecutive days where Flag = 1 for a specific account. So in the example, you can see that for Account ABC, Flag=1 on 1/3, 1/4, and 1/5. On those days, for that account, the Target result would be 1 (1/3), 2 (1/4), and 3 (1/5). That's different than DEF, for example, which had Flag=0 on 1/4. As a result, the Target result for that account on that day would be 0. But on 1/5, the Target result = 1, since Flag=1 on 1/5. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Target Result = 
  var curD = [Date]
  var curA = [Account]
  var lastReset = CALCULATE(MAX([Date]), ALL('Gap'), 'Gap'[Account] = curA && 'Gap'[Date] <= curD && 'Gap'[Flag] = 0)
  var result = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Gap'), ALL('Gap'), 'Gap'[Account] = curA && 'Gap'[Date] > lastReset && 'Gap'[Date] <= curD)
  RETURN COALESCE(result, 0)
```

Added v2 below looking at the last 7 days from today.

```
Target Result v2 = 
  var curD = [Date]
  var curA = [Account]
  var ageDays = TODAY() - 6 // 7 days
  var filterSet = FILTER(ALL('Gap'), 'Gap'[Account] = curA && 'Gap'[Date] >= ageDays)
  var lastReset = CALCULATE(MAX([Date]), filterSet, 'Gap'[Date] <= curD && 'Gap'[Flag] = 0)
  var result = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Gap'), filterSet, 'Gap'[Date] > lastReset && 'Gap'[Date] <= curD)
  RETURN IF(curD >= ageDays, COALESCE(result, 0) )
```

Comment: One more question...if i wanted to adjust the above so that it only took into consideration the last 10 days (and not the entire production timeseries), would i just convert var curD = [Date] to var curD = [Date]-10? Thanks again

Comment: Last 10 days of each entry or of today? Are you simply wanting the max to be 10?

Comment: I think i'm looking for the second option you mentioned. Last 7 days might make it conceptually easier for me actually. So instead of looking at the entire dataset, only  looking from 10/27/23-11/3/23, for example.

Comment: Updated the answer above with v2 to look at the last 7 days.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much for all the help.